# How do I use sass to make my class name dynamic depending on vue.js binding?

Tags: vue.js, sass

Currently I have this div which load the value with vue.js binding.

```
<div :class="`progress-bar w-${progress.value}`">
```

and in the css, how to I use sass to make css class name dynamic? Which means if the above code compiled to become

```
<div class="progress-bar w-88">
```

there will be a css class generated by sass will be

```
.progress-bar.w-88 {
  width: 88%;
}
```

Comment: Using dynamic style (:style) is option for you?

Comment: yes, it works with dynamic style. But, the only issue is I also need the `hover` selector

Comment: hover you can apply on the progress-bar class regardless of the width amount

Comment: @BallonUra, can share the code as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
@for $i from 0 through 100 {
  .progress-bar.w-#{$i} {
    width: #{$i}%
  }
}
```

[Documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for)

Comment: When I tried it, it complaints syntax error at `width: $i%`: specifies the width of the content area, padding area or border area (depending on 'box-sizing') of certain boxes. 
Syntax:<viewport-length>{1,2} term expected scss

Comment: when you are doing `@for` in scss you need to wrap the value with `#{}`.
instead of `width: $i%;` it should be `width: #{$i}%;`.
the reason you need to do this is to generate the value in actual string rather than a variable.

Comment: Thank you! @Renesansz

Comment: @Renesansz thanks. It still has the same syntax error at `width: #{$i}%;`. Could it be due to eslint rules?

Comment: It works now after I change it to `width: $i * 1%;`. Sorry, I awarded the bounty and unable to undo it.

Comment: No worries @Steve, glad you found your answer 

Answer (score 1):

SCSS:

```
.progress-bar {
      background: #DEE2E3;
      border-radius: 99px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 5px;
      position: relative;overflow: hidden;
      
      &::before {
        border-radius: 99px;
        position: absolute;
        height: 5px;
        background: #f5c70f;
        content: '';
        width: 0;
        transition: width .2s;
      }
    }
    
    
    @for $i from 0 through 100 {
      .w-#{$i}::before { width: $i * 1% }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="progress-bar w-10"></div>
 <div class="progress-bar w-88"></div>
<div class="progress-bar w-100"></div>
```

Comment: Codepen Link:
https://codepen.io/amirnaeem/pen/VwKKoLP

Comment: But, strange. It only works for the first element after I add hover selector.